# Magento2- UI Component - Remove form validation for telephone

Tags: magento2, form-validation, ui-form

I have tried to override the form validation for `telephone` which added in core file `vendor\magento\module-customer\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml` as follow:

```
 <field name="telephone">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
 </field>
```

Tried to override this file in local module and changed the line

```
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

This remove only the mandatory (*) mark from address form for telephone number but the validation remain same.

If you removed the complete entry from base file (`vendor\magento\module-customer\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml`) then complete validation get also removed. anyone know how we can override the form config validation using local module?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment making telephone optional requires quite a lot of coding. There is a [discussion at github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1691)  about this resulting in a module (github:/zsoerenm/magento2-optionaltelephone) being developed thats sole purpose is exactly this. However, the magento devs have already implemented a solution in core to address this. [The fix](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8519)  in the development branch now and hopefully will soon be in master.